# How to draw a half circle on a plot?

Tags: r, plot, draw, trigonometry

I am trying to draw some half circles on a plot, using the trigonometric functions in R.
So here is what I have :

```
matPoints <<- as.data.frame(cbind(X=c(-1, -(sqrt(3)/2), -(sqrt(2)/2), -0.5, 0, 0.5, sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(3)/2, 1), Y=c(0, 0.5, sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(3)/2, 1, sqrt(3)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0.5, 0)))

plot(x = matPoints$X*W, y = matPoints$Y*W)
```

For the moment, it prints each point on the plot. What I want to do here is to trace a smooth line between points so it gives me a beautiful half circle of center (0, 0) and of scale W.

Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
x <- seq(0, pi, length.out = 500)
W <- 3
plot(cos(x) * W, sin(x) * W, type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: It works very well, thank's, now how do you put 2 other lines on it? Is it possible?

Comment: @TFC You may use `lines` function to add line. what kind of line do you want? I can add code for those.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you @Park

Answer (score 4):

Since the general equation of a circle is x^2 + y^2 = r^2, you can mimic it like below as well,

```
r=3 # radius
x <- seq(-r,r,0.01)
y  <- sqrt(r^2 - x^2)

plot(x,y,type="l")
# plot(c(x,x),c(y,-y),type="l") for a full circle.
```

gives,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility using complex numbers, and `polygon` to draw a closed shape.

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2))
polygon(1i^(seq(0,2,l=100)))
```

[image]

Using this method you can easily change the centre, scale, rotation, fill colour etc:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2))
polygon(2*(1i^(seq(0,2,l=100)))*1i^.5 + .1-.3i, col="red")
polygon(1i^(seq(0,2,l=100)), col="blue")
```

[image]